# Difference between “Mac Developer” and “3rd Party Mac Developer Application”

Tags: xcode, macos, mac-app-store

What is the difference between `Mac Developer` and `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` profiles in `Code Signing Identity`? Which one is for Mac App Store distribution?

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was scratching my head at this for some time too.

This is explained in *"Tools Workflow Guide for Mac"*, found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH1-SW1

(as usual with Apple, these topics are pretty cryptic and not always explained well).

Here are some relevant paragraphs:

> The name of the certificate begins with the text “Mac Developer” for a
>   Mac Development certificate, “3rd Party Mac Developer Application” for
>   a Mac Submission certificate, and “3rd Party Mac Developer Installer”
>   for a Mac Installer certificate

And

> The development certificate should appear in the My Certificates
>   category in Keychain Access. The name of the certificate begins with
>   the text “Mac Developer:” followed by your name for a development
>   certificate as shown in Figure 3-2

And

> If you are a team agent or admin and you requested a distribution
>   certificate, both your distribution and developer certificates appear
>   in the My Certificates category in Keychain Access as shown in Figure
>   3-3. The distribution certificates begin with the text “3rd Party Mac
>   Developer” followed by the type of certificate and your team name.

Finally,

> **Signing Using a Mac Submission Certificate**
>
> Before you create an archive, sign your project using the Mac
>   Submission certificate.
>
> ...
>
> Only a team agent or admin can obtain and use distribution
>   certificates for this purpose. If you haven’t already done so, create
>   your distribution certificates as described in “Creating Signing
>   Certificates” now. Later when you submit to the Mac App Store, you are
>   asked to select the Mac Installer certificate to sign the installer
>   package.
>
> Next, set the Code Signing Identity build setting to the Mac
>   Submission certificate that begins with the text “3rd Party Mac
>   Developer Application” as described in “Signing an App.” Run your app
>   to verify that this is the build you want to release.

So basically, *"Mac Developer:"* certificate is a personal developer certificate for just signing the code. *"3rd Party Mac Developer"* certificate if you want to submit to the App Store and have the required role to do so.

Not to be confused, note that there is also *"Developer ID Application"* and *"Developer ID Installer"* certificates. These are used to sign the application for distribution outside of the App Store. Described in the same document under *"Distributing Outside the Mac App Store"*

**UPDATE:** The link to Apple's documentation originally mentioned is now obsolete. This is now better explained in the updated "App Distribution Guide" here - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW41

Comment: Hello do you encounter a problem, when setting Signing to `Mac App Store` changes Build Settings Code Signing Identity to `Mac Developer`? And vice-versa if I set Code Signing Identity to `3rd Party Mac Developer Application:...` Xcode changes Signing to `None`. Stuck with it, maybe you know the answer? Thanks.